# Angular input type radio with ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I am having hard time figuring out how to work with radio buttons in Angular. Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/3bp2t4ma/

```
<div class="form-row full-width pull-left text-center check-as">
                                        <label> <input name="ticket" type="radio"
                                             ng-model="ticketType.type" ng-value="query"> Query
                                        </label> <label class="complaint-check"> <input name="ticket"
                                            type="radio" ng-model="tickeType.type"  ng-value="complaint">
                                            Complaint
                                        </label>
                                    </div>

                         {{ ticketType | json }}
```

And javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function Main($scope) {

 $scope.ticketType={type: 'query'};


}
```

Any idea why `ticketType` becomes empty when I click on radio button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is one obvious typo in the Complaint button: ng-model="tickeType.type"

You're missing a t.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using ng-value instead of value?

ng-value will try to look for the value in your scope (the value of $scope.complaint), rather than just using the string 'complaint'.